# Conditions for uniqueness of solution of dual

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, karush-kuhn-tucker, constraint-programming

Consider the following linear programming (hereafter, problem **[1]**)
$$
\max_{y\in \mathbb{R}^J}c'y\\
\text{s.t. } b_t' y \leq a_t \text{ }\forall t\in \{1,...,T\}
$$
where $c$ is a $J\times 1$ vector of reals, $y$ is a $J\times 1$ vector of unknowns, $b_t$ is a $J\times 1$ vector of reals, $a_t$ is a real scalar.

It can be shown that this problem is equivalent to problem **[2]**
$$
\min_{x\in \mathbb{R}^T} x'a\\
\text{s.t. } x\geq 0_T\\
\sum_{t=1}^T x_t b_t=c
$$
where  $a\equiv (a_1,...,a_T)$, $x$ is a $T\times 1$ vector of unknowns, $0_T$ is the $T\times 1$ vector of zeros, $x_t$ is the $t$-th element of $x$.

I'm trying to understand under which conditions on the elements of [1] we can ensure uniqueness of the solution, $x$, of [2]. The hint of the exercise in the book is "constraint qualification". I'm a beginner and I can't find any simple explanation online on what it means and how I can apply it here. Could you help?

Comment: by "uniqueness of the solution, $x$", you mean that the dual problem [2] has a unique solution? Or that a solution to the primal problem [1] corresponds to a single solution of the dual problem?

Comment: Thanks. I mean that the dual problem [2] has a unique solution with respect to $x$.

Comment: I think the requirement should be that there is no degeneracy in a basic feasible solution (BFS) of the primal problem which is also dual feasible. Such a situation can lead to multiple dual BFS (you need to be familiar with duality). Therefore the conditions on [1] should be: define a subset $\mathcal{I}$ of vectors $b_t$ with carnality $J$. Then: 1) The primal is feasible 2) the vectors $b_t\in\mathcal{I}$ span $\mathbb{R}^n$ 3) $\forall b_t\notin\mathcal{I}$ we have $b_t^ty\neq a_t$. This is a sketch, you can use the conditions to formulate a full proof

Comment: Thanks. How does it relate to constraint qualification? Could you kindly outline an answer with a proof (also a sketch of the proof would be OK)?

Comment: Also, is my understanding on how $\mathcal{I}$ is constructed correct: take any $J$ vectors from $\mathbb{R}^J$ such that they span $\mathbb{R}^J$; the collection of these vectors is $\mathcal{I}$.

Comment: Constraint qualifications says that the set of active constraints (where they hold with equality) at $x^*$ are linearly independent. On the one hand this is a "looser" condition then the one I gave, since you require independence only at $x^*$. On the other hand, it requires you to know $x^*$, which you don't know before solving the primal problem. So choosing either depends on the question, this is for you to consider. In both cases, it ensures that the primal optimal solution corresponds to a unique dual solution, and hence to a unique optimal dual solution.

Comment: Sketch: Let $\mathcal{I}^*$ be the set of active constraints at $x^*$. If the system $b_t^t y=a_t$, for all $b_t\in\mathcal{I}^*$ does not have admit a unique solution then it's possible for $\sum_{t\in\mathcal{I}^*}x_tb_t=c,\; x_t\geq 0$ has more then one solution (in terms of $x_t$). If that is the case then all dual solutions correspond to the same primal solution $x^*$ and they are all optimal, i.e. not unique.

Comment: @iarbel84 Thanks: I think I'm confused on what is $x^*$. Is a solution of the dual or of the primal? In your last comments, you refer to it as a solution of the primal ("... to the same primal solution $x^*$ ...)".

Comment: You understood $\mathcal{I}$ right. If you're looking for an answer that follows "constraint qualifications" then go with the comment above this, meaning use the condition that at $y^*$ the active constraints form a basis of $\mathbb{R}^j$

Comment: Sorry, every time I wrote $x^*$ it should be $y^*$. Normally for the primal program we use $x$, this is why I got confused. Also $\mathbb{R}^n$ should be $\mathbb{R}^j$.
Your book's notation is not standard :)

Comment: Thanks, if you can give a formal answer I can validate it and give a plus 1.